# Matrices, Sets, Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image] I have the solution I still don't get it, does anyone know where 15*9 come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the two sets: $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Z} |~ 4\leq 3x \leq 48\}$ and $B=\{x\in \mathbb{Z} | 2\leq 4x \leq 36\}$ and are asked to find the size of $|A\times B|$

For finding the size of $|A|$, notice that you could have alternatively written $A$ in set builder notation instead as: $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Z} |~ \frac{4}{3}\leq x \leq \frac{48}{3}\}$ or equivalently $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Z} |~ 1.\overline{3}\leq x \leq 16\}$ by simply dividing all parts of the inequality by $3$.  Thus, $A = \{2,3,4,\cdots,16\}$ and you can see that there are $15$ elements in the set.

Similarly, $B$ can be rewritten as $B=\{x\in \mathbb{Z} | 0.5\leq x \leq 9\} = \{1,2,3,\cdots,9\}$.  Again by counting, you see that $|B|=9$

Now, $A\times B = \{(a,b)|~a\in A, b\in B\} = \{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),\cdots,(2,9),(3,1),(3,2),\cdots(3,9),\cdots,\cdots,(16,1),\cdots,(16,9)\}$

There are 15 different possible beginning numbers, and for each of those there are 9 possible end numbers.  Hence $|A\times B| = |A|\cdot |B| = 15\cdot 9$